# Is REST API essential in web application when displaying dynamic content?

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, symfony

I'm working on simple symfony3 application - task manager. Not many entities: User, Task and Project.

At this time default setup is used. Symfony3 with FOSUserBundle on back-end and Bootstrap on the front. It works great, but there is no AJAX calls at all.

I want to involve some AJAX in my application - for example this mentioned Task. Now, when user clicks "this task is done" he is redirected and page refreshes. I want to just remove this task from the list and display baloon.

After some research I found out that in order to be able to do this (ajax calls and dynamically modify the page instead of refresh) I have to make an API.

So I started to make the JSON API using FOSRestBundle, FOSOAuthBundle... Now, after 3 days all I have is new branch with code messed up completely. I'm not sure if it does make sense to make API and consume it immediately in the same app.

I think that I should write two apps - one for REST API and one for interaction with user. Or maybe Symfony REST API on the backend and some Angular on the frontend?

**To sum up:**

Really small symfony3 application.
Dynamic interaction needs to be involved.
Is any of my approaches good, or should I implement something else?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are on a good way by using REST-API, since it's cleaner and it separates output from logic.

It's always a good approach to get a JSON-object from your REST-API and use it's data to generate an HTML-output on the client-side.

To use your example with the deleting of the task, you have two approaches here:

#### Replace whole HTML-Output of the task-list with new one via AJAX

```
<div class="task">some task <a href="url-to-done-function/1">done</a></div>
```

- click delete button
- AJAX-call of REST-function that renders the new list
- put the AJAX-retreived data into a `div`

#### BETTER: Delete only the div from the DOM

```
<div class="task" id="task1">some task <a href="url-to-done-function/1">done</a></div>
```

- click delete button
- AJAX-call of REST-function that deletes the specific task and return success/error via JSON
- check if success and remove the div with id="task1"

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, this is not exactly what I needed. My question was more like, should I put an effort for creating REST API for such little thing, and if I should, whether to separate API from the frontend in two applications.

Comment: I'd recommend to put effort even in such little things. That makes you get used to best practices. But, you absolutely don't need to create two applications. You can have your service be a REST API and the frontend-app itself.